# Choose kernel version in OpenEmbedded

Tags: build, linux-kernel, angstrom-linux, openembedded, bitbake

I want to build Angstrom kernel on *Ubuntu 13.04 host machine* using OpenEmbedded.

```
git clone git://github.com/Angstrom-distribution/setup-scripts.git
cd setup-scripts
MACHINE=beagleboard./oebb.sh config beagleboard
MACHINE=beagleboard./oebb.sh update
MACHINE=beagleboard./oebb.sh bitbake virtual/kernel
```

The reason of building kernel is to be able to cross-compile a kernel driver on host machine, targeting on Angstrom distribution *(BeagleBoard)*. Beagleboard runs a prebuilt image of 2.6.32.

As I know, the cross-compile must target not only the Angstrom distribution, but the same kernel version that BeagleBoard runs. How does OE choose "preferred" version? Is there any way I can choose the kernel version that BitBake will build?

Answer (score 5):

Depending on PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel you choose, you can specify the version
this is an example:

```
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel ?= "linux-yocto"
PREFERRED_VERSION_linux-yocto ?= "3.10%"
```

remember the '%' means that numbers following 3.10 doesn't matter.

another example

```
PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel ?= "linux-imx"
PREFERRED_VERSION_linux-imx ?= "3.10.2"
```